# Float right pagination in asp.net mvc vs2012

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, pagination

I am trying to float to right page navigation in webgrid in vs2012. I tried `.replace()` for `<tfoot><tr><td>` but I seem to have got it wrong. Please help me out to show page navigation on the right of the footer.

Sample of code given below..

```
@grdDept.GetHtml(
    tableStyle: "webGrid", 
    firstText: "<<",
    lastText: ">>",
    previousText: "<",
    nextText: ">",

    columns: new[] {  
        grdDept.Column("AssignTo",header: "Assign To",format:@<text><div id="div-AssignTo">@item.AssignToName </div></text>)  
    } 
).ToString().Replace("<tfoot><tr><td","<tfoot><tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td"));
```